# Ошибка при сериализации массива (коллекции)

Tags: c#, wpf

при выполнении сериализации массива объектов выскакивает ошибка:
**System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: "Тип "System.Windows.Shapes.Ellipse" в сборке "PresentationFramework, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" не помечен как сериализуемый."**

Гугли ничего нет (либо плохо гугли). Можете подсказать, что это, с чем это едят и как исправить. В классах прописано [Serializable]

```
//Объявление массивов
  public ObservableCollection<FullElement> VisMod = new ObservableCollection<FullElement>();
  public ObservableCollection<EdgeLine> Edgeln = new ObservableCollection<EdgeLine>();

  Dictionary<string, int> ShortNameOfElement = new Dictionary<string, int>();



  //Меню
  private void NewProject(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
  {
     VisMod.Clear();
     Edgeln.Clear();

  }
  private void ExitFromProject(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
  {
     this.Close();
  }

  //метод сериализации
  private void SaveOfProject(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
  {
     System.Windows.Forms.SaveFileDialog svFilDial = new System.Windows.Forms.SaveFileDialog();
     svFilDial.Filter = "Project files(*.eec)|*.eec|All files(*.*)|*.*";
     svFilDial.FileName = "Zhep";

     if (svFilDial.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
     {
        Stream myStream = svFilDial.OpenFile();

        var serial = new BinaryFormatter();

        serial.Serialize(myStream, VisMod);
        myStream.Close();

        System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("Сохранение прошло успешно");

     }




[Serializable]
   //Модель UserControl
   public class FullElement : INotifyPropertyChanged
   {

      Ellipse ellipseOfUC;

      public Ellipse EllipseOfUC
      {
         get { return ellipseOfUC; }
         set
         {
            ellipseOfUC = value;
         }
      }

      Ellipse ellipseOfUC2;

      public Ellipse EllipseOfUC2
      {
         get { return ellipseOfUC2; }
         set
         {
            ellipseOfUC2 = value;
         }
      }

      Point pos1;

      UserControl selectedControl;

      public Point Pos
      {
         get { return pos1; }
         set
         {
            pos1 = value;
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
               PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Pos"));
         }
      }

      public UserControl SelectedControl
      {
         get
         {
            return selectedControl;
         }
         set
         {
            selectedControl = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("SelectedControl");
         }
      }

      public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
      private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
      {
         PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
      }


      internal void MoveRef(Vector vector)
      {
         Pos += vector;
         if (PropertyChanged != null)
         {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Pos"));
         }
      }
```

Comment: Покажите код, чтобы не играть в телепатов.

Comment: ну вроде ясно же написано `"System.Windows.Shapes.Ellipse".... не помечен как сериализуемый."`

Comment: 1. То что вы пометили свой тип сериализумым, не делает сериализуемыми типы, которые ваш тип использует внутри себя (класс Ellipse например), о чем вам и говорит текст ошибки. 2. Очень-очень плохая идея сериализовать элементы UI. Заведите модель, по данным которой их можно построить и сериализуйте модель, а сами элементы оставьте в покое.